# NPM does not update readme

Tags: node.js, npm

I released a module yesterday and made changes to the  readme soon after. The readme has not updated since the first release. How do I force an update?

The module:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app-fullstack

Comment: Did you publish the package again ?

Comment: Yes, I've published several times.

Answer (score 8):

I was experiencing the same issue and the following steps worked for me.

1. `npm cache clean --force`
2. `npm version patch`
3. `npm publish`

Comment: having this issue with npm 5.3.0. npm cache clean does not seem to fix the issue

Comment: This has not worked for me either.  I have no indication that it's a malformed .md file.  Idk what's going on